# How to read tensorflow dataset caches without building the dataset again

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have created a dataset (`tf.data.Dataset`) with fairly complicated transformations and I have cached it to a file. My question is how can I read the content of that dataset again without reconstructing the dataset object again. For example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()
db = tf.data.Dataset.range(10)
db = db.cache('/tmp/range')
for v in db:
    print(v)
# /tmp/range.data-00000-of-00001  /tmp/range.index files are created

# later, you could restore the dataset from a method like this:
new_db = tf.data.Dataset.from_cache('/tmp/range')
```

The idea is to build the dataset in another context and use it without building the complicated input pipeline that I had before.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure if you complete one epoch of reading the dataset, the next time you start a new training, it will still read from this cache file even if you make changes to your pipeline.